# Java - How to read next line and store multiple data separately in their own variable?

Tags: java, network-programming

I've come to a problem in passing data from one client class to another server class. I made variables to store each information the client sends to the server, and it uses an if statement that rejects service if either address or password is incorrect, else otherwise.

However, I've come to a problem, when user typed in password; then address. The data is automatically passed on the first round. Instead of client send password data, and store data in password variable in the server. Then client send address, store the data in address variable. It just sends both, and store both in one variable.

**I want to display:**

```
Password received: unlo91\ (made up password)
Address received: localhost
```

**Instead I get:**

```
Password received: unlo91\localhost (made up password)
Address received: null
```

Is there a method to, "Right. Client just sent password. Store it in PW var. OK, don't store in PW var now because that is already in use (or used once already). Move on to next available variable (address) to store the next."

**Server:**

```
cliPass = fromClient.readLine(); 
System.out.println("Client entered... " + cliPass );
cliAd = fromClient.readLine(); 
System.out.println("Client entered... " + cliAd);
```

**Client:**

```
    System.out.println("Type password");
    myPass = fromUser.readLine();
    toServer.writeBytes(myPass);


    System.out.println("Type address");
    myAd = fromUser.readLine();
    toServer.writeBytes(myAd);
```

Comment: It looks like you need a collection of some sort of data structure class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really asking the right question, the problem you have is caused by a previous oversight, and if you fix it you can skip this problem.

When you read the line in on the client with `fromUser.readLine();`, the String you recieve will have had its line separator removed, as stated in the Javadocs:

> public String readLine() throws IOException
>
> Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> **Returns**:
>       A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Therefore, if you add them back in to the String before you send it to your server like so:

```
System.out.println("Type password");
myPass = fromUser.readLine() + System.lineSeparator();
toServer.writeBytes(myPass);


System.out.println("Type address");
myAd = fromUser.readLine() + System.lineSeparator();
toServer.writeBytes(myAd);
```

Your server code should work as expected, as they will then be counted as separate lines once again.

Or if you really want to do that, you should consider a `Map<String, String>` if you have an unknown number of variables.

Comment: Thank you. The line separator did the job. Nice info too.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ArrayList<String>`.

ArrayList has a method, `add`, that adds a new value to the end of the collection. When you're done, you can use a `for` or `foreach` loop over the ArrayList and get each value added to it one at a time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

If you need to store a bunch of strings but associate them with names, then you want a `HashMap<String,String>`.

You can do `.add("username", "tom")` and `.add("password", "hunter12")` on a HashMap, and to get a value you do `.get("username")` and you get "tom" back.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the readline method returns the string without a line break.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29

When you use it on the server there is no line break, so it continues to wait for the end of the line.

Try this on your client:

```
System.out.println("Type password");
myPass = fromUser.readLine();
toServer.writeBytes(myPass + "\n");


System.out.println("Type address");
myAd = fromUser.readLine();
toServer.writeBytes(myAd + "\n");
```